# OpenCV face detection, how to crop and save face?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, crop, face-detection

I'm using OpenCV 3 on Ubuntu. the following code is used to detect a face in an image and save the cropped part. The output isn't being shown but the cropped image is saved in my folder.

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

// Function Headers
void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame);

// Global variables
// Copy this file from opencv/data/haarscascades to target folder
string face_cascade_name = "/home/sruthi/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
string window_name = "Capture - Face detection";
int filenumber; // Number of file to be saved
string filename;

// Function main
int main(void)
{
    // Load the cascade
    if (!face_cascade.load(face_cascade_name)){
        printf("--(!)Error loading\n");
        return (-1);
    }

    // Read the image file
    Mat frame = imread("/home/sruthi/Downloads/pic.jpg");

    // Apply the classifier to the frame
    if (!frame.empty()){
        detectAndDisplay(frame);
    }
    else{
        printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
        //break;
    }

    int c = waitKey(10);

    if (27 == char(c)){
        //break;
    }

    return 0;
}

// Function detectAndDisplay
void detectAndDisplay(Mat frame)
{
    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat frame_gray;
    Mat crop;
    Mat res;
    Mat gray;
    string text;
    stringstream sstm;

    cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);

    // Detect faces
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

    // Set Region of Interest
    cv::Rect roi_b;
    cv::Rect roi_c;

    size_t ic = 0; // ic is index of current element
    int ac = 0; // ac is area of current element

    size_t ib = 0; // ib is index of biggest element
    int ab = 0; // ab is area of biggest element

    for (ic = 0; ic < faces.size(); ic++) // Iterate through all current elements (detected faces)

    {
        roi_c.x = faces[ic].x;
        roi_c.y = faces[ic].y;
        roi_c.width = (faces[ic].width);
        roi_c.height = (faces[ic].height);

        ac = roi_c.width * roi_c.height; // Get the area of current element (detected face)

        roi_b.x = faces[ib].x;
        roi_b.y = faces[ib].y;
        roi_b.width = (faces[ib].width);
        roi_b.height = (faces[ib].height);

        ab = roi_b.width * roi_b.height; // Get the area of biggest element, at beginning it is same as "current" element

        if (ac > ab)
        {
            ib = ic;
            roi_b.x = faces[ib].x;
            roi_b.y = faces[ib].y;
            roi_b.width = (faces[ib].width);
            roi_b.height = (faces[ib].height);
        }

        crop = frame(roi_b);
        resize(crop, res, Size(128, 128), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR); // This will be needed later while saving images
        cvtColor(crop, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY); // Convert cropped image to Grayscale

        // Form a filename
        filename = "";
        stringstream ssfn;
        ssfn << filenumber << ".jpg";
        filename = ssfn.str();
        filenumber++;

        imwrite(filename, gray);

        Point pt1(faces[ic].x, faces[ic].y); // Display detected faces on main window
        Point pt2((faces[ic].x + faces[ic].height), (faces[ic].y + faces[ic].width));
        rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);
 }

    // Show image
    sstm << "Crop area size: " << roi_b.width << "x" << roi_b.height << " Filename: " << filename;
    text = sstm.str();

    putText(frame, text, cvPoint(30, 30), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.8, cvScalar(0, 0, 255), 1, CV_AA);
    imshow("original", frame);

    if (!crop.empty())
    {
        imshow("detected", crop);
    }
    else
        destroyWindow("detected");
}
```

But at the end of the execution I'm getting:

> sruthi@sruthi-5547:~/c++$ ./crop
>   pure virtual method called
>   terminate called without an active exception
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: Your code works for me without errors. If you want to see the `imshow`ed images you need to call `waitKey()` after.

Comment: @Miki I didnt understand what you said. Could you please explain?

Comment: You need to call `waitKey()` after `imshow`, or you won't see the image.

Comment: @Miki I added waitKey() right after the imshow line. But still I can see the error.

Comment: if (!crop.empty())
    {
        imshow("detected", crop);
     cv::waitKey(10);  
}

Comment: That's correct. I'm not able to reproduce your error (on Windows tou code works ok), so probably you should follow the advice in the given answer.

Comment: Try `cv::waitKey();`, without the parameter `10`.

Comment: yeah, didn't see the `10`. Just leave it empty or put `0`, or your window will close after 10 ms.

Comment: Thank you both so much,it worked.

Comment: glad it worked. consider then marking @CronoTrigger post as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two issues here.

First, your code works fine, but you should add `cv::waitKey();` after `imshow` to prevent the window from closing (it will close after pressing a key).

Second, there is a bug in OpenCV 3.0.0 that causes the `pure virtual method called` error. If your program runs ok, I'd bet the error message is because of the bug. If you get the latest (and unreleased) OpenCV version from its github repository, it will be fixed.

Comment: Tested with OpenCV 3.0 (not latest unreleased version) and 2.4.9 and I don't get any error. Are you sure about this?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger The output isnt being showed irrespective of adding waitKey after imshow. How to proceed next?

Comment: I'm sure there is some bug in the released OpenCV 3.0.0 that can cause the `pure virtual method called` error. See [this](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/issues/5174) for example. I'm not sure if that is what's is happening to OP, but the symptoms seem to match.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can do this:

```
import cv2
import sys

cascPath = sys.argv[1]
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30),
        flags=cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE
    )

    # Draw a rectangle around the faces
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('c'):
        crop = frame[y: y + h, x: x + w] 
        cv2.imwrite("face.jpg", crop)

# When everything is done, release the capture
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```